# How do you only import `for` from `Perl6::Controls`?

Tags: perl

Test case:

```
use 5.026;
use Perl6::Controls qw(for);

for (1..10) -> $n {
    say $n;
}

loop {};
```

Expect:

Can't call method "loop" without a package or object reference

Got:

infinite loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
use Perl6::Controls qw(for);
BEGIN {
    delete $^H{'Keyword::Simple/keywords'}{"loop"};
}
...
```

which I stumbled into running your script through [`B::Deparse`](https://metacpan.org/pod/B::Deparse).

---

To pick and choose the keywords you want to keep, you could say

```
use Perl6::Controls;
BEGIN {
    my @keep = ...;    # e.g.  @keep = qw(for);
    my %keywords;
    @keywords{@keep} = @{$^H{'Keyword::Simple/keywords'}}{@keep};
    $^H{'Keyword::Simple/keywords'} = \%keywords;
}
```

Comment: $^H{'Keyword::Simple/keywords'} is a super global variable, so make sure that @keep has all the keywords from all the other packages that define keywords as well

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Looking at the source-code for [Perl6::Controls](https://metacpan.org/source/DCONWAY/Perl6-Controls-0.000006/lib/Perl6/Controls.pm) it uses it's own import method to define all the new keywords using [Keyword::Declare](https://metacpan.org/source/Keyword::Declare). It ignores any parameters passed on the use line.